# MONGO DB RELACIONAR DOS COLECCIONES

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

Quisiera ver si me pueden apoyar a relacionar dos colecciones de mongo
Tengo lo siguiente:
    MODELO CLIENTES:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ClientesSchema = Schema({
    razon_social: String,
    correo1: String,
    }, { versionKey: false });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Cliente', ClientesSchema);
```

Y MI MODELO CUENTAS:

```
    var CuentasSchema = Schema({
    tipo_cuenta: String,
    descripcion: String,
    clabe: String,
    tipo_registro: String,
    cliente: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "clientes" }
}, { versionKey: false });


module.exports = mongoose.model('Cuentas', CuentasSchema);
```

MI CONTROLADOR CUENTAS:

```
var Cuenta = require('../../Modelos/cuentas/cuentas');

var controller = { search: (req, res) => {
            // Sacar el string a buscar
            var searchString = req.params.search;

            // Find or
            Cuenta.find({
                    "$or": [
                        { "tipo_registro": { "$regex": searchString, "$options": "i" } }
                    ]
                })
                .sort([
                    ['date', 'descending']
                ])
            .populate('clientes')
                .exec((err, cuentas) => {
                    if (err) {
                        return res.status(500).send({
                            status: '¡Error!',
                            message: 'Error En La Petición De Datos.'
                        });
                    }
                    if (!cuentas || cuentas.length <= 0) {
                        return res.status(404).send({
                            status: '¡Error!',
                            message: 'No Existen Cuentas Que Coincidan Con El Criterio De Busqueda.'
                        });
                    }
                    return res.status(200).send({
                        status: 'Correcto',
                        cuentas
                    });
                });
        }, //fin del search
module.exports = controller;
```

lo que quiero es que al buscar una cuenta por tipo_registro = cuenta me traiga los datos del cliente pero no lo hace solo me devuelve los de la cuenta.

```
"status": "Correcto",
"cuentas": [
    {
        "_id": "5da4caf89c8a72006819dee2",
        "tipo_cuenta": "tipoCuenta2",
        "descripcion": "cuenta 3",
        "clabe": "123245679876543",
        "tipo_registro": "cliente",
        "cliente": "5da77041b6d51c4f409fe8cd",
        "proveedor": "ddsd"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5da4cb559738e9439c6d035d",
        "tipo_cuenta": "tipoCuenta2",
        "descripcion": "descrrre",
        "clabe": "asdasdasdasdasdasd",
        "tipo_registro": "cliente",
        "proveedor": ""
    }
]
```

}

ya intente con populate pero no me regresa nada sigue igual, me podrian orienar de como hacer que regrese los datos del cliente y sus cuentas asociadas.

Comment: El problema que veo en tu código, es que en tu modelo *Cuentas* tienes un campo llamado *cliente* (en singular) y en tu controlador estás tratando de hacer `populate` a un campo llamado *clientes* (en plural). Por favor verifica eso, ya que parece un problema de error tipográfico. Saludos

Comment: en efecto, eso tenia mal, aunque también otro compañero lo hizo pero el en esta linea especificamente  cliente: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "clientes" } quito el .Types despues de Schema y le funciono, muchas gracias.